# Java Web View - Native Find

Tags: java, webview, javafx

I am currently using a JavaFX WebView to display some HTML.

Is anyone aware of any features to use a "Find" method that is on a normal browser?

Can't seem to figure out how to activate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

WebView has no "Find/Search" support for text in a web page.

I created a feature request for this:

- [RT-23383 Text search support for WebView](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-23383).

This feature request is currently a couple of years old and is not scheduled for implementation, so I doubt it would be implemented anytime soon unless somebody contributed a patch for it to the open-jfx project (which again I don't think would happen anytime soon).

Ways you might be able to implement this feature are:

1. Modify the WebView OpenJFX Java and C source code (very difficult IMO).
2. In Java write a [document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#documentProperty--) tree traversal routine to search for things.
3. See if you can do something like inject some JQuery/JavaScript code into the document which makes the document text searchable, possibly communicating with the modified document over the WebView Java/JavaScript bridge (this is probably a fairly fragile solution).

I won't try to provide any implementation for any of the above in this answer as it is non-trivial.